# HTML markup & ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, partial-views

I have parts of the web page which I would like MVC3 to serve to client pages. Instead of making them static in everysite. I have sites which have reoccurring markup in parts in the page, such as banner, navigation. In some sites I will need to customize the markup a little. So I need to be able to extend if possible.

Can someone please tell me if MVC3 is ideal as a solution to this? I am thinking partial views. Can you inherit & extend partial views?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Views can be implemented for your needs. For example, you can use them as follows :

```
  @model string[]

  @if((bool)Model[0]) { 

    <span>I like it to be this way.</span>

  } else { 

      <span>No, I like it to be that way.</span>
  }
```

Inside a view, you can call this partial view as follows :

```
@Html.Partial("myPartialView", new string[] { "true" })
```

You can pretty much pass anything to partial view as `Model`.

If you plan to use those partial views on multiple applications, I encourage you to create Nuget package for those Partial Views and get them into each application through Nuget Package Manager.

Comment: so I guess you can't "inherit" partial views?

Comment: @user742276 Would you like to use them as template? If so, what you are looking for is Layouts not Partials.

Comment: can you please illustrate what you mean by using Layout to do this?

Comment: @user742276 See this video : http://beta.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-3-quick-hits/mvc-3-%E2%80%93-razor-layouts

Answer (score 0):

Banners, navigation, custom panels etc - all these are the components that you might want to add, combine, remove or update as time goes. Yes, partial views would do the job easily, but in my opinion, inheritance isn't a way forward.

Your partial views should be based on view models. For example: OrderPanelViewModel, UserMenuViewModel, CustomPanelViewModel. Each partial view is now a component, a feature that you can add,remove, modify as you feel suited.

What happens if you want to combine banner and a user menu? It's not going to work if they inherit from the same view model, but it will work if they have their own view models.

For example:

```
public class MyCustomPaneViewModel{
   public UserMenuViewModel UserMenu { get; set; }
   public UserBannerViewModel UserBanner { get; set; }
}
```

You can now base your view on this view model

```
@model YourDll.WebUI.Models.MyCustomPaneViewModel

@section main_content{

   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserMenu, "UserMenu")
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserBanner, "UserBanner")

}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation but this approach still leaves me with having to store my markup outside MVC3. I was hoping I could integrate the markup into the view...

Comment: What do you mean by saying outside of mvc3? The first code snippet is your M - model, when the second is your V - view

Comment: the markup has to exist some where, so I currently have them in XML, XSL file. Using the model, I will still have to read them from the XML/XSL content files. I was hoping I could abstract the content in MVC structure instead, as I would prefer code rather than XML/XSL.